# SQL - Include where condition if variable is not null

Tags: sql

I am trying to add a where condition to be checked only if variable 
@schoolId is not null otherwise return all results. Please
know that If condition cannot be used because it is a very large query.
This is just a part of it.

```
Table Name - Students

Id Name   SchoolId
1  John      6
2  Mark      6
3  Alice     12
4  Prince   null
```

Query

```
Select * from Students st
where st.SchoolId = Case when @schoolId  is not null then @schoolId else st.SchoolId End
```

So if @schoolId is null, I want to return all 4 rows. I want it to return results where SchoolId is null too if variable is null. Currently with above query it does not return 4th row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Boolean logic instead of `case` expression :

```
where (@schoolId is null) or
      (st.SchoolId = @schoolId);
```

Comment: This won't work because it will only return null value if schoolId is not provided

Comment: . . . No, it will return all rows when `@schoolId` has no value.

Comment: @LearnAspNet. . . In your query with `case` expression, it will return 3 rows only when  `@schoolId` is null. because `null` = `null` will evaluate as `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `or`:

```
where (st.SchoolId = @schoolId or @schoolId is null)
```

You have two separate conditions and this checks both of them.

Comment: This won't work because it won't return the 3rd row if SchoolId is not provided

Comment: @LearnAspNet . . . This does exactly what  you are asking for.  Why would you say the 3rd row would not be returned?  This returns ALL rows when `@schoolid` is null.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. if you edit your answer in any way. I can upvote you. It does not let me change the vote

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
declare @schoolId int

If @schoolId is null
Select * 
from dbo.Students st
Else
Select * 
from dbo.Students st
where st.SchoolId = @schoolId
```